# Capistrano linked_dirs doubles end of path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I recently upgraded to rails 5 and capistrano 3.5.

Now im facing the issue, that every folder in :linked_dirs gets double-symlinked:

In my deploy.rb

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids',      'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')
```

This results in:

```
✔ 02 user@example.com 0.023s
✔ 04 user@example.com 0.023s
  05 ln -s /var/www/app-dir/shared/tmp/cache /var/www/app-dir/releases/20161108113840/tmp/cache
✔ 05 user@example.com 0.025s
  05 ln:
  05 failed to create symbolic link '/var/www/app-dir/releases/20161108113840/tmp/cache/cache'
  05 : File exists
```

It searched the documentation, stack overflow and github issues for hours now..

The behaviour is the same for: `append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache" ...`

- I tried capistrano 3.4, 3.5
- I removed the whole app-dir (then it worked for one deployment)
- I removed specific code in my deploy.rb
- I completely removed the :linked_dirs
- I tried several ways to configure :linked_dirs

I would be glad if someone has any idea what else i could try. :(

Comment: You could try running `cap production doctor`, which provides additional troubleshooting data.

Comment: Have you tried the new append method of Capistrano 3.5? `append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "public/system", "public/uploads"`

Comment: i got this fixed by just adding ROLES=app to the command. Capistrano was doing the same tasks for different roles